# Why this code doesn't work in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do some lines between 2 points, that also change the intensity of the colors, my idea is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=black] (-2,0) circle (2pt);  
    \draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (2pt);  

     \foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\x*10}
      \foreach \Point in {(0,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,-2),(0,-3)}
      {
      \draw [black!{\z}] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(-2,0) \Point (2,0)};
      };
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But it gives me a mistake that I don't know how to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the braces around `\z`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=black] (-2,0) circle (2pt);  
    \draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (2pt);  

     \foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\x*10}
       \foreach \Point in {(0,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,-2),(0,-3)}
       {
       \draw [black!\z] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(-2,0) \Point (2,0)};
       }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, looking at the code I am wondering why you are redrawing the same paths over and over in different gray levels. Are you by chance trying to do something like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=black] (-2,0) circle (2pt);  
    \draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (2pt);  

       \foreach \Point [count=\X] in {(0,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,-2),(0,-3)}
       {
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{\X*10}
       \draw [black!\Z] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(-2,0) \Point (2,0)};
       }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooo yes, now I get it. Thanks, that was what I was trying.